# Menu doesnt show on button hover

Tags: html, css

I have problem with my menu. When i use hover on my button i want that menu shows, but it doesn't work. I tried everything. I can't even change color of menu at hover. I think that is problem with CSS.

```css
.menurozwijane {
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 8%;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: none;
}

.przycisk {
  position: relative;
}

.przycisk:hover .menurozwijane {
  display: block
}

.menurozwijane ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6%;
  top: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.menurozwijane li {
  width: 17%;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.ikonam {
  font-family: 'icons';
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #da9057;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Strona główna</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">O nas</a></li>
    <li class="przycisk"><a href="#">Oferta</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Realizacje</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li id="pomoc">?</li>
    <li id="facebook">0</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="menurozwijane">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">c</div>Elektryczne</li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">f</div>Kamery</li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">i</div>Inteligentny dom</li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">l</div>Systemy<br/> nagłośnienia</li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">a</div>Przeciwpożarowe</li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">d</div>Kontroli dostępu<br/> i rejestracji czasu pracy</li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">g</div>Alarmowe</li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">j</div>Instalacje SZR</li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">m</div>Odgromowe</li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">b</div>Klimatyzacja</li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">e</div>Instacje światłowodowe</li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">f</div>Domofonowe</li>
      <li>
        <div class="ikonam">k</div>Instalacje TV</li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp) on how to make a dropdown menu.

Comment: I dont use that id in my styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the position of the dropdown **menurozwijane** for the selector to work

Move it inside the **przycisk**

See snippet code:

```css
.menurozwijane {
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 8%;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: none;
}

.przycisk {
  position: relative;
}

.przycisk:hover .menurozwijane {
  display: block
}

.menurozwijane ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6%;
  top: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.menurozwijane li {
  width: 17%;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.ikonam {
  font-family: 'icons';
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #da9057;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Strona główna</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">O nas</a></li>
    <li class="przycisk">
      <a href="#">Oferta</a>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="menurozwijane">
        <ul>

          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">c</div>Elektryczne</li>
          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">f</div>Kamery</li>
          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">i</div>Inteligentny dom</li>
          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">l</div>Systemy<br/> nagłośnienia</li>
          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">a</div>Przeciwpożarowe</li>
          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">d</div>Kontroli dostępu<br/> i rejestracji czasu pracy</li>
          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">g</div>Alarmowe</li>
          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">j</div>Instalacje SZR</li>
          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">m</div>Odgromowe</li>
          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">b</div>Klimatyzacja</li>
          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">e</div>Instacje światłowodowe</li>
          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">f</div>Domofonowe</li>
          <li>
            <div class="ikonam">k</div>Instalacje TV</li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Realizacje</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li id="pomoc">?</li>
    <li id="facebook">0</li>
  </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Css:**
Use `+` Selector:

```
.przycisk:hover  + .menurozwijane {
  display: block
}
```

**HTML:**

Change place `.menurozwijane` like this :

```
<li class="przycisk"><a href="#">Oferta</a></li>
<div id="myDropdown" class="menurozwijane">
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">c</div>Elektryczne</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">f</div>Kamery</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">i</div>Inteligentny dom</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">l</div>Systemy<br/> nagłośnienia</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">a</div>Przeciwpożarowe</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">d</div>Kontroli dostępu<br/> i rejestracji czasu pracy</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">g</div>Alarmowe</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">j</div>Instalacje SZR</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">m</div>Odgromowe</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">b</div>Klimatyzacja</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">e</div>Instacje światłowodowe</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">f</div>Domofonowe</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">k</div>Instalacje TV</li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

```css
 .menurozwijane {
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 8%;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: none;
}

.przycisk {
  position: relative;
}

.przycisk:hover  + .menurozwijane {
  display: block
}

.menurozwijane ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6%;
  top: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.menurozwijane li {
  width: 17%;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.ikonam {
  font-family: 'icons';
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #da9057;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Strona główna</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">O nas</a></li>
  <li class="przycisk"><a href="#">Oferta</a></li>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="menurozwijane">
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">c</div>Elektryczne</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">f</div>Kamery</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">i</div>Inteligentny dom</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">l</div>Systemy<br/> nagłośnienia</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">a</div>Przeciwpożarowe</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">d</div>Kontroli dostępu<br/> i rejestracji czasu pracy</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">g</div>Alarmowe</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">j</div>Instalacje SZR</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">m</div>Odgromowe</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">b</div>Klimatyzacja</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">e</div>Instacje światłowodowe</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">f</div>Domofonowe</li>
    <li><div class="ikonam">k</div>Instalacje TV</li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
    <li><a href="#">Realizacje</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li id="pomoc">?</li>
    <li id="facebook">0</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```